# Can the matrix expression $D-A^{-1}DA$ be simplified (for diagonal $D$ and symmetric $A$)?

Tags: matrices

I can't seem to find a way to extract the $D$ from the inside or let $A$ and its inverse interact in some way. Is this the simplest form of this expression?

Comment: Yes, this is the simplest form of the expression.

Comment: Are you trying to determine which matrices will commute with diagonal matrices?

Comment: You could write the expression as 
$$
A^{-1}(AD - DA)
$$
which I personally like better.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, I'm manipulating big matrix expressions for an optimization application and I'm trying to figure out the simplest form and the fastest, least time and memory-wasting order of the computations.

Comment: Nice rewrite. I actually have another $A^{-1}$ on the other side in my actual problem, so it's $A^{-1}(AD-DA)A^{-1}$, which looks pretty nice. Due to symmetry it's also equal to $A^{-1}(AD-(AD)^T)A^{-T}$. Any ideas to further collapse this for computation purposes?

Comment: I don't see any helpful rearrangements.  $(AD - (AD)^T)$ will be skew symmetric, and the entire result will be skew-symmetric, if that helps.

Comment: Actually this second version with the inverse on both sides is equal to $DA^{-1} - A^{-1}D$, which is simpler. Also, its elements can be written neatly as $(A^{-1})_{i,j}(d_i-d_j)$

Comment: Ah, you're right; I missed that

Answer (score 1):

You can't "extract the $D$" because $D$ is not uniquely determined by this.  For example, you can always add a multiple of the identity matrix $I$ to $D$ and it will not change $D - A^{-1} D A$.

Comment: By extract, I meant converting it to a formula where $D$ appears only once.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use $D$ more, since it has the simpler form?